# Add AoO to Pathfinder Beginner Box rules

Tags: pathfinder-1e, opportunity-attack

In the simplified rules of Pathfinder Beginner Box there is no attack of opportunity rule. Can I just introduce this rule and play the Black Fang's Dungeon without any other changes? Does it break something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you the GM? You can do whatever you want. I honestly don't think it can possibly break the game, however I believe that it will make the dungeon a little harder.
Players get killed by AOOs for three reasons:

---

1. The fighter decides to charge past the front line monsters to hit the squishy spellcaster in the back. He draws 10 AOOs from the frontliners and dies.
2. The monsters run past the dead fighter, and attack the wizard in the back line. The wizard survives the first round, decides to run away, but then dies from AOOs as he flees for his life.
3. The ranger has stood and fought the front line monsters for a bit before taking too much damage. He decides to run, and dies to AOOs.

I love AOOs as a game mechanic. They make you worry about your decisions, and I love that tension. However, they are hard on newbies and they are the worst when things are already going badly.

If you do introduce them, explain to the fighter that he is supposed to stand between the monsters and the wizard. Also, consider introducing total defense. If you are teaching new players I would write that down on a card, and not bring it up unless things are going badly and the party wants to retreat.

Total Defense: 
You can defend yourself as a standard action. You get a +4 dodge bonus to your AC for 1 round.